# How to remove border from last div

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="drop-menu">
<div class="drop-menu-header"><i class="fal fa-bell"></i>&emsp;Notifications</div>
<div class="drop-menu-item"> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" id="462">
                Date of Birth: <b>2017-08-30</b><br>
                Father: <b>KULDEEP SINGH</b>
                Mother: <b>SUKHDEEP KAUR</b>
            </a> </div>
<div class="drop-menu-item"> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" id="466">
                Date of Birth: <b>2018-08-22</b><br>
                Father: <b>SANJU</b>
                Mother: <b>ALKA</b>
            </a> </div>
<div class="drop-menu-item"> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" id="565">
                Date of Birth: <b>2016-12-10</b><br>
                Father: <b>RAVINDER SINGH</b>
                Mother: <b>SUKHPAL KAUR</b>
            </a> </div>
```

in this code last-child not working.
how can i setup css for this code
i'm new to html and css

Comment: What is your current CSS? And what are you intend to do?

Comment: Can you include your CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :last-of-type selector.

```
.drop-menu-item:last-of-type {
  /* your styles */
}
```